# Windows 10 update created a recovery partition - How to hide that partition?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, windows-update, recovery-partition

There was a Windows 10 update which created (or made visible) a recovery partition in this PC. Since it is 449MB in size and only 35,8MB are free, every few minutes I get a warning that it is low on disk space. Now I found this: [Disable the low disk space popup warning in windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1123543/disable-the-low-disk-space-popup-warning-in-windows-10) to disable the warning, but since I didn't create this partition (it's a custom pc) and I can't use it, but also don't just want to delete it, is there a way to also hide that partition from "My Computer"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that just unassigning the drive letter will do the trick:

> 1. Open Computer Management on the local computer by right clicking on
>      Computer in Windows Explorer and choose Manage. Then click on Disk
>      Management in the left hand pane.
>
>    (Or just type diskmgmt.msc into the run dialog)
> 2. Right click on the shaded area for Drive D: System reserved (or whatever the name is / letter) in the
>      lower right hand window.
> 3. Click on Change drive letter or paths
> 4. Highlight D:(**letter of the partition**) and click remove
>
> If you receive error messages that the drive might be in use or that
>   programs might not run correctly, don't panic. It is OK to remove the
>   drive letter. Once a letter is not assigned, the drive will not appear
>   in Windows Explorer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Trying to link a related question is tough[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1318683/low-disk-space-on-recovery-partition?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 8):

I encountered this same problem after the Windows 10 Spring 2018 update. I was unable to unassign the drive letter according to the instructions from Tiago Caldeira that used Disk Management, however these command line instructions did work for me:

- Open Command Prompt in Admin
- Enter `diskpart`
- Enter `list volume`
- Enter `select volume [number of your volume]`

  - For example: `select volume 0`
- Enter `remove letter=[drive letter of your volume]`

  - For example: `remove letter=f`
- You should see the message `DiskPart successfully removed the drive letter or mount point.`

I hope this information helps!

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I found it helpful.

Comment: The `remove volume=f` did not work for me. I had to use `remove letter=f`

Comment: @Caz you are correct! I'll edit my answer. Thanks!

Comment: For me, after computer restart, drive is appearing again

Comment: @Somnium Had the same problem.  Problem resolved when using the mountvol x: /D instead of diskpart suggested by arvy

Answer (score 3):

Run this on DOS Prompt running as administrator:

```
mountvol X: /D
```

Change X: to the assigned drive letter. Done.