# Cannot find this location in REGEDIT: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\ Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer

Tags: windows-10, disk-space, notifications, regedit

I'm getting a really annoying low disk spam from windows for an OEM partition.  Was searching how to turn this off and found this [this article.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/555622/how-to-remove-the-low-disk-space-warning)

It directs me to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\ Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer, but I do not have this Explorer folder available to me, I get as far as Policies.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: An OEM partition is for recovery, not the used/accessed by users in a normal OS session. That said the solution is not disabling such warning messages but just removing the drive letter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable the low disk space popup warning in windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1123543/disable-the-low-disk-space-popup-warning-in-windows-10)

Comment: While I believe this to be a duplicate, the simplest solution to this problem is to remove the drive letter from the partition[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1319266/how-to-clean-an-e-drive-new-recovery-drive-since-windows-10-1803-on-hp-laptop).  So I have also linked to another possible duplicate.

Comment: How about just  modifying the register in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\ Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`,without the policies, I often use gpo to push the registry without the key `policies`.

Comment: Sorry for. The delay in responding all. Been moving house and its been mental. I did in the end just remove the letter as GabrielGarcia suggested. This resolved the issue completely.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a certain Registry Key, just create it. Not all possible used Keys are there from the start. Sometimes you have to create multiple level of keys to get the correct path that is required to hold a value.

Comment: I did not realise I was able to just do this, thank you for the advice. In the end, I just removed the letter as it was an OEM partition this solved it.